Make sense of integral representation of the Gamma function for $s<0$
The integral defining Gamma, $\int_0^\infty e^{-t} t^{s-1} dt$, is not convergent for $s \leq 0$. So we have to resort to the functional equation $\Gamma(s)=\Gamma(s+1)/s$ to define it for such $s$. Is there a way to interpret the defining integral directly to evaluate Gamma? I know this can be done for instance for the most familiar series representation of the zeta function at negative integers, using smooth approximation and Euler Maclaurin formula. Is it possible to do something similar for the Gamma integral say at $s=-1/2$?

This answer might be useful to you
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2204020/definition-of-the-gamma-function-for-non-integer-negative-values
